# innerHTML not changing on window load

Tags: javascript, php, innerhtml

Below is the layout of my page.

```
php function to fetch data from db
css that has got some animations for my divs
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var myVar = <?php echo callFunctionFromPHP() ?>;
        alert(myVar);
        document.getElementById("waiting").innerHTML = "Text after load";
    }
</script>
<body>
<div id="waiting">Current text</div>
```

When the page loads, I intend for 'Current text' to be shown and after having loaded page, I want javascript to call php, which internally will fetch data from db, and once done I want to change the div's text to new text.

But this is not working. Although I know that the javascript function is getting called because if in my JS function I only keep the innerHTML line then the page loads with the 'after' text. Also, I know that my php function is working fine because when I do 'inspect page source' it shows the correct data from database.

but my alert command doesnt work. Can someone help me with what is wrong here?

Note : I understand that this is perhaps not the best coding practice (calling php from js function like this), but I am only prototyping for now.

Comment: *when I do 'inspect page source' it shows the correct data from database.* -- can you post what's in your page source? It sounds like whatever's being echo'd by PHP is not valid javascript code, causing the browser to stop executing JS

Comment: You **CAN'T** call PHP function *from JS*, since PHP runs server-side and the result sent to the browser, to evaluate as JS. To do something similar, you'll need an ajax call

Comment: You CAN have the php function run and return some value which the javascript can then evaluate @FZs

Comment: @ChristopherBradshaw Yes, but can't call it ***from JavaScript*** as the asker wrote. (That code runs before page load.)

Comment: Even if this was prototyping you should never do this :P

Answer (score 2):

You will want to wrap output in double quotes:

```
var myVar = "<?php echo callFunctionFromPHP() ?>";
```

Comment: Ooh! Good catch!

Comment: That sort of depends on what `callFunctionFromPHP` does. If it does `return json_encode($something);` you **don't** want to wrap it in quotes

Comment: @rickdenhaan you are correct. But without further details, it's just a guessing game.